# How to set RecurrenceData values in SharePoint Calendar List using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, sharepoint-2013, office365

How to set RecurrenceData values in SharePoint Calendar List using Javascript ?

```
var recurreciveData = "<recurrence>
                           <rule>
                               <repeat>
                                   <daily dayFrequency=\"" + repeatDayz + "\" />
                               </repeat>
                               <windowStart>
                                   " + repeatStrtDate.toISOString() + "
                               </windowStart>
                               <windowEnd>
                                   " + repeatEndDate.toISOString() + "
                               </windowEnd>
                           </rule></recurrence>";
var data = JSON.stringify({
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data."+ listName +"ListItem"
    },
    "Title": title,
    "Location": location,
    "RoomId": room,
    "EventDate": strtDate,
    "EndDate": endDate,
    "fRecurrence": true,
    "RecurrenceData": recurreciveData,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For creating a **repeating** event via SharePoint REST API the following properties needs to be specified:

- `EventDate`
- `EndDate`
- `fRecurrence` set to `true`,
- `EventType` set to `1`,
- `RecurrenceData`

**Example**

```
var listTitle = "Calendar";
var itemProperties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.CalendarListItem" },
    'Title': 'Event 123',
    'EventDate' : '2015-06-03T09:00:00Z',
    'EndDate' : '2017-06-03T09:00:00Z',
    'fRecurrence': true,
    'EventType' : 1,
    'RecurrenceData': '<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><daily dayFrequency="1" /></repeat><repeatForever>FALSE</repeatForever></rule></recurrence>'
};

createListItem(listTitle,itemProperties)
.done(function(item)
{
    console.log('Event has been created');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where

```
function executeJson(options) 
{
    var headers = options.headers || {};
    var method = options.method || "GET";
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(options.method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: options.url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if("data" in options) {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}



function createListItem(listTitle,payload){
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url,
        "method": 'POST',
        "data": payload});
}
```

Comment: Hi Vadim! Thank You! Changed to JSOM, works well, but have problem opening in "Calendar" view: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215859/jsom-calendar-recurring-task-item-does-not-exist-it-may-have-been-deleted-by Didn't You have this problem?